# Why does predict_proba function print the probabilities in reverse order?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am using scikit-learn to implement classification using Logistic Regression.
The class labels are predicted using `predict()` function, while the predicted probabilities are printed using `predict_proba()` function.

The **code snippet** is pasted below:

```
# Partition the dataset into train and test data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(ds_X, ds_y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42) 

y_pred = logreg.predict(X_test)                             # Predicted class labels from test features
y_predicted_proba = logreg.predict_proba(X_test)            # Predicted probabilities from test features
```

The **predicted labels** are printed as

```
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1.......... and so on
```

The corresponding **predicted probabilities** are printed as

```
array([[ 0.03667012,  0.96332988],
       [ 0.03638475,  0.96361525],
       [ 0.03809274,  0.96190726],
       [ 0.01746768,  0.98253232],
       [ 0.02742639,  0.97257361],
       [ 0.03676579,  0.96323421],
       [ 0.02881874,  0.97118126],
       [ 0.03082288,  0.96917712],
       [ 0.65332179,  0.34667821],
       [ 0.02091977,  0.97908023],
                   .
                   '
       and so on
```

Observe,
 the first predicted label - **1**
         the first predicted probability - [ **0.03667012,  0.96332988**]
**Why is 0.03667012 printed first, instead of 0.96332988 ?**
Should it have been the other way?

Comment: The first column is the predicted probability for class 0, the second is the predicted probability for class 1. Are you saying they should be printed in highest-to-lowest order?

Comment: No, the way I interpreted was the complement of the probability gets printed first.
But now, my doubt is cleared. The predicted probability for class 0 gets printed first, followed by the probability for class label 1. Thanks.

Comment: Does the order of data-points used from X_test is same for predict_proba and predict ? Is there any documentation suggesting the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The column 0 is the probability for class 0,

and the column 1 is the probability for the class 1.

If you have n classes the output probabilities shape will be (n_examples, n_classes).

Comment: Is it possible that column 0 is actually the probability for class 1 while column 1 for class 0? How do I know that the probabilities are given in the order of the natural integers?

Answer (score 2):

You can use: 
`logreg.classes_` to resolve what element in your probability array corresponds to which class.  In your case its `[False,True]`

Comment: That makes sense! Sometimes it happens that the order of probabilities are not given in the order of natural integers. It is always better to check the classifier's internal order.